# Rails redirecting to /undefined on call to edit and delete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, carrierwave

I have a simple photo gallery on a site, and am having some trouble when I invoke either the edit or delete paths. I click on the button and the page acts like it is going to load, then goes to an error page. Here is the trace from the console:

```
Started GET "/photos/17/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-10-12 09:41:08 -0700
Started GET "/photos/17/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-10-12 09:41:08 -0700
Processing by PhotosController#edit as HTML
Processing by PhotosController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"17"}
  Parameters: {"id"=>"17"}
Photo Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "photos".* FROM "photos" WHERE "photos"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 17]]
Photo Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "photos".* FROM "photos" WHERE "photos"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 17]]
Album Load (7.9ms)  SELECT "albums".* FROM "albums"
Album Load (7.9ms)  SELECT "albums".* FROM "albums"
Rendered photos/_form.haml (35.7ms)
Rendered photos/_form.haml (35.7ms)
Rendered photos/edit.haml within layouts/application (38.9ms)
Rendered photos/edit.haml within layouts/application (38.9ms)
User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Rendered layouts/_navbar.html.haml (5.0ms)
Rendered layouts/_navbar.html.haml (5.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 187ms (Views: 174.4ms | ActiveRecord: 9.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 187ms (Views: 174.4ms | ActiveRecord: 9.4ms)
```

Then I get this immediately after, before the edit page loads:

```
Started GET "/undefined" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-10-12 09:41:08 -0700
Started GET "/undefined" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-10-12 09:41:08 -0700

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/undefined"):
```

I've looked over my controller and methods and haven't seen anything that would suggest the need for it to look for the /undefined path. What is worse is that it doesn't happen every time, which made me think there was something wrong with my ruby installation or something. If that was the case, it would not give the error on Heroku (which it does) and would probably error out in other applications I work on (which it doesn't).

Controller:

```
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @photo.update(photo_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @photo, notice: 'Photo was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @photo }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @photo.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

def destroy
  @photo.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to photos_path, notice: 'Photo was successfully destroyed.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end
```

Model:

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

  belongs_to :album
  validates_presence_of :image
end
```

When I notice that it is redirecting me, I can just browse to the picture itself fine (photos/8), but the edit path is still kicking me to the /undefined (photos/8/edit).

Comment: Do you have any JS that might be causing this as "undefined" is more of a JS term than a ruby one.

Comment: That is a great question, I will investigate that.

EDIT: Here is my application.js file: 
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require lightbox
//= require_tree .

The only other thing being imported is Justified Gallery, that shouldn't have anything to do with it I would think.

Comment: do you have some sort of security filter in place, perhaps in the ApplicationController?

Comment: Application controller is just the standard: protect_from_forgery with: :exception. Not seeing anything in any of the other controllers, especially not that would make it work some of the time.

Comment: Something else I just noticed is that someones when I just hit the back button from the /undefined error page, the right edit page loads up for me.

Comment: there can be error , in link_to helper , can you paste your view code , just of link

Comment: Try turning off javascript - I'm 99% sure its a javascript redirect. As @engineersmnky allready has pointed out ruby has nil, not the giant clusterf*ck that is `undefined` and `null` in javascript.

Comment: +1 for it being javascript. Could be turbolinks setup or some ujs you've got in your view.  Would be good to see the `#edit` method in your controller (seeing as you've given the `#edit` logs) and check for any `data-` attributes in your view.

Comment: The edit method is empty except for `@photo = Photo.find(params[:id])`

Comment: Here are the links that are giving me trouble

`%td= link_to image_tag(photo.image.thumbnail.url)
%td= link_to "Edit", edit_photo_path(photo), :class => "btn btn-default"
%td= link_to "Delete", photo_path(photo), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, :class => "btn btn-danger"`

Answer (score 0):

I realise (and hope) you might have solved this already, but I've been banging my head against the wall due to a similar problem - a GET request to /undefined route. Luckily, I was able to solve it and this might help people with similar problems.

To explain my situation - I have some AJAX calls and I suspected it might have something to do with that, even though I did not build up any URLs with variables that could be undefined.. or so I thought (I was partially right, though).

I was fetching some information (including image URLs to be rendered in view thereafter) based on data returned by an API in JSON format. I hope you see where I am going with this :)
Turns out one image (for that specific API request, I am sure there are other such cases which I haven't yet found) had no URL defined. As I passed the json data to a constructor, I expected the image URL to be defined and inserted that into the image src attribute. The URL was, however, apparently undefined. Therefore, instead of loading the image via absolute path to the API's CDN, as the src had no http(s)://, it tried to load it from local server. As the variable with image url was undefined, the image src attribute pointed to a relative /undefined route. Hence a GET request to "/undefined" route.

I should note that this was not an ajax call per se, the get request was a result of using data from ajax call to construct an image src attribute. The fact that I used that data for constructing a google maps infowindow HTML structure (which included an image in it) only compounded the problem as the missing image (due to undefined src) would only show up after clicking on a specific google maps marker.

So, for your case (while it might not be relevant for you anymore, might be for someone else) - make sure you look at image src attributes as images will start loading immediately after your page (or in case of ajax loading and constructing HTML image tags afterwards) loads. Hence one 'normal' request that gets processed as it should. If, however, an image src attribute is "undefined", it will then immediately start a get request to "/undefined" route.